# Перспектива, геометрия 3D

Tags: математика

Прочитал вот [эту](http://habrahabr.ru/post/243011/) статью и возникло пару вопросов.

x y координаты точек проецируются на ближнюю плоскость и изменяются под cvv, почему z координата не должна подвергаться проективным изменениям ( деления на z ) очевидно, но z точек все равно должны запиханы в cvv, это вроде понятно.

Взгляните на формулу f(z) = a * 1/z + b, как пришли к 1/z. Я думал они должны что то сделать для уничтожения проективных изменений (очевидно) и оставить преобразования в cvv, посмотрите Zndc, но не тут то было.

Там есть абзац:

> Выражение для z находится по-другому. Вместо того, чтобы рассматривать
>   функцию вида az + b мы будем рассматривать функцию a · 1/z + b, потому
>   что в дальнейшем, когда мы будем реализовывать буфер глубины, нам
>   нужно будет линейно интерполировать величину, обратную z-координате.
>   Мы не будем рассматривать этот вопрос сейчас, и просто примем это за
>   данное.

Линейно интерполировать? Меня гугл не спас, я не понял что это, а дальше, по статье, они так и не рассказали.

Когда они говорят, "возвращение в пространство w = 1", нормализуют (делением на w) - они имеют введу ведь d = 1 проекционную плоскость (по подобным треугольникам), я не ошибся ?

Почему выбрали вычисления по матрицам? Чем удобно?

Сильно ли будет влиять iee754 в cvv? Почему бы не использовать int [max, min]?

Comment: Ну так а почему не обратиться непосредственно к автору? Предлагаете мне все это прочитать и на все 6 Ваших вопросов ответить одним экраном текста?

Comment: Я думал тру парни этим закусывают и не будет для них проблемы мне объяснить, не уверен что автор еще жив (в смысле, бывает онлайн на этом ресурсе) Если ответите на вопросы, низкий поклон и все пользователи, задавшиеся теми же вопросами, будут благодарны.

Comment: Ох ладно сейчас гляну и отпишу что-нибудь. Но вообще необходимость software renderingа, когда видеокарты производят массово и над драйверами для них думают целые корпорации годами, в моей голове слабо укладывается

Comment: Ну почитайте тогда учебник по линейной алгебре какой-нибудь хороший. Там всякие линейные/векторные пространства, вектора, тензоры, кватернионы, методы интерполяции. Матрица это ведь не просто таблица из чисел, а еще и оператор в линейном пространстве. Умножение вектора на нее - естественный и очевидный способ преобразования его координат.

Comment: @uskabuska, ты хочешь всё и сразу. Такой подход как правило обречен на провал. Задавай разные вопросы по отдельности. Начни с этого: "Что такое линейная интерполяция?"

Comment: Вы предлагаете удалить вопрос, разбить его по частям и задать много вопросов? :c иррационально

Comment: @igumnov я пониманию базовые штуки из школьного курса, если на вопросы ответите и автора годной книги посоветуете - было бы шикарно :)

Comment: @uskabuska, иррационально задавать много вопросов в одном. Тебе повезёт если ты получишь ответ хотя бы на один.

Comment: @uskabuska Короче, там нужна эта интерполяция, чтобы просто координаты текущего пикселя получить из z координат вершин. Посмотри алгоритмы построения Z-буфера(буфера глубины) из исходной сетки.[Вот например](https://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/courses/fall2007/zbuffer.html) [или вот в комментариях такой же вопрос](http://habrahabr.ru/post/248179/) И в нем обычно используют с фиксированной запятой числа, а не с плавающей. Дальше не буду расписывать, т.к. сам софтверных рендеров не писал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С одной стороны, я рекомендую вам почитать [этот курс](http://habrahabr.ru/post/248153/)

Статья, которую вы прочитали, является плодом творчества студента, который, к сожалению, старается завернуть поумнее. Курс, на который я ссылаюсь, написан людьми с противоположной стороны экзаменационного стола. Мы хотели сделать все как можно доступнее.

И на некоторые вопросы постараюсь ответить здесь:

Интерполяция - это получение значения функции (саму функцию при этом знать не нужно) между какими-то известными ее точками. Слово "линейная" означает, что между этими точками мы проводим прямую (по двум точкам в привычной нам геометрии Евклида такая прямая однозначно задана) и берем на этой прямой искомое промежуточное значение. DiHalt это дело неплохо [описал](http://easyelectronics.ru/avr-uchebnyj-kurs-kusochno-linejnaya-approksimaciya.html)

Вычисления по матрицам выбраны из соображений унификации. Любое *движение* (за математическим определением движения - в Википедию (а вообще, геометрию в школе надо было учить, а не гексаэдр на нее возлагать)) в трехмерном пространстве можно записать матрицей 4x4 в проективном к нему пространстве.
О самих матрицах - читайте все тот же курс по первой ссылке.

Про iee и вычисления с фиксированной запятой. Классик 3D, Джон Кармак, написал DOOM и DOOM 2, полагаясь именно на фиксированную запятую. Благодаря этому, демки в старинном думе можно было сохранять, просто записывая нажатия клавиш (и для игры по сети тоже - достаточно передавать нажатые клавиши каждый кадр), ведь целые числа везде считаются одинаково. Поэтому рациональное зерно в использовании фиксированной запятой есть.

Однако, современные рендеры используют аккуратные вычисления с плавающей запятой, да и многие математические функции (sin, cos, ln) аппаратно ускорены.
Главное - не копить погрешность. А то и верчение кубика за пару часов его изуродует.

Comment: Спасибо, уже в процессе анализирования. А Вы автор рекомендованной статьи? Как с вами можно пообщаться напрямую? И можно ли?)

Comment: @uskabuska я один из соавторов, но не главный. Обращайтесь.

Comment: Ааа как? На stackoverflow есть лс? Или можно прям тут длинные дискуссии вести?

Comment: Полагаю, что полезнее здесь.

Comment: Длинные дискуссии в [чат комнатках](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com). Можете создать свою по 3D графике и рендерингу, её вроде нет еще. Там есть логи, можно звездочки ставить, форматировать и удобнее чем через комментарии, а тут пропадет скорее всего и через 10-15 комментариев будет лимит и движок начнет сам предлагать перейти в чат.

Comment: @igumnov спасибо, создал http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29080/3d--